# Centered view pager with secondary page hints

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've read every SO post about centered view pagers with hints but I haven't been able to reproduce it in my own code. The suggestions I've gotten have been either too simple and didn't work or too complex and would take too long to understand (1000+ lines of code).

I am using the support library viewpager, and I'm able to get my views centered. However when they are centered I am unable to get more than 1 view to show up in the view pager at a time. If I `setPageMargins` to a negative value large enough to bring in a second view into the screen, the margins cut off (clip) the first view (and yes I've tried every possible combination of setting backgrounds to null or transparent so that this doesn't happen -- no luck). If I set `getPageWidth()` to return 0.7f it brings the second view onto the screen as well, but pushes the first view over to left by the same amount.

I've also tried setting the clipChildren and clip to padding values but that didn't fix it either.

The code I'm using right now pushes the selected view by 30% to the left and brings the second view into the screen by 30%.

I also tried copying the code from here: https://github.com/Pixplicity/MultiViewPager

That didn't work in my project for whatever reason even though I tried my best to ensure all the settings were the same.

Comment: "That didn't work in my project for whatever reason" -- did you try running the included sample project? "I've also tried setting the clipChildren" -- did you use code like the third approach in [my blog post on multiple `ViewPager` children](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html)?

Comment: I ran the sample project and it did work there. I couldn't figure out the difference. But I was unable to copy my views into the sample project because there were a lot of dependent code and it would take forever to fix up all the errors to make it work. I haven't tried your approach. I'll give it a try, its probably the only one I didn't try yet.

Comment: Looking at your suggestion, it wouldn't work for my implementation. As I need to be able to swipe by page, not 2 sub-pages. I'd need to know which page was selected so that I can act on the view in that page.

Comment: The bottom-most suggestion on that page also did not work for me. It didn't center my view, and it messed up the background image in the view and misalligned the paint I had drawn on the view as well.